# Как расположить div'ы как на картинке? (html css)

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как расположить элементы так же как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.ultra {
  display: inline-block;
}

#header1 {
  width: 100%;
}
}
.super {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#russia {

  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0)
}
#arrow {

  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(230,230,230)
}
#number {

  font-size: 9pt;
  background-color: rgb(20,20,20)
}
#reg {

  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(30,30,30)
}
#call {

  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgb(40,40,40)
}
#enter {

  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(50,50,50)
}
```

```html
<header id='<header'>
  <div id='header1'>
    <div class='ultra' id='call'> <p class='super'>звонок по России бесплатный </p></div>
    <div class='ultra' id='number'> <p class='super'>8-800-775-45-44</p> </div>
      <div class='ultra' id='enter'><p class='super'>ВОЙТИ</p></div>
      <div class='ultra' id='reg'><p class='super'>РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</p></div>
      <div class='ultra' id='russia'><img  class='super' src='imgs/russia.png' width='15' height='10'></div>
      <div class='ultra' id='arrow'><p class='super'> \/ </p></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important;
}

.header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.left-section,
.right-section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-section a,
.right-section a {
  margin-left: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.left-section span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.right-section a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.flag {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 17px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flag img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flag::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  font-size: 33px;
  color: black;
  top: 0px;
  right: -18px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="left-section">
            <span>звонок по России бесплатный</span>
            <a src="#" class='fhone'>8-800-775-45-44</a>
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
            <a src="#">ВОЙТИ</a>
            <a src="#">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a>
            <div class="flag">
                <img
                    src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Flag_of_Russia.svg/33px-Flag_of_Russia.svg.png'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```